# Threading not closing and when code is ran more than once, it causes system to slow to a crawl

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, websocket, twisted

This issue has had me stumped for about 2 weeks. I haven't seen anything online that is specific to my situation and I am too new to generalize other solutions. I can connect one time, and the feed stops displaying after 1 msg. I can get it to work once but I have to reset my kernel every time. But when I try to reconnect, print(bm.conns) shows a new object being created but it never displays a new feed. I have tried asyncio with the same results,from what I read, theres is no authentication and wss over asyncio sockets but I was desparate. I have tried making a run class in asyncio that calls the process_msg function. and that just hangs indefinitely, I have tried passing the loop object to my process message with asyncio, I never did figure that out. I have looked for code from traders but all I have seen is API calls and no sockets. I have considered doing a time.sleep() for a given value, but I would really like to disconnect and reconnect every so often as well as having option to stream live data. Thank you for any help anyone can offer.

```
from binance.client import Client
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager


client = Client('MY_KEY', 'MY_SECRET')
bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
started = False


def process_message(msg):

    print(msg)
    print('Stopping WebSocket')
    bm.stop_socket('!ticker@arr')
    bm.close()




conn = bm.start_ticker_socket(process_message)
print(conn)        
print(bm._conns)


if not started:
    started = True
    bm.start()
```

Comment: It looks like I have figured out what the issue is, I'm just not sure how to fix it. bm is a threaded subclass. After the execution of code, the thread remains open. I have tried the join() method but that hasn't been successful. I have read all the warnings on killing threads in Python but if I call the code more than once, the time of execution gets longer and longer because the number of threads keeps increasing.

Comment: What is the third-party `binance` library used in this code?  Is it https://pypi.org/project/python-binance/0.6.9/ ?

Comment: Sorry, it is at this link.
  https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/blob/master/binance/websockets.py
 I am studying threads now as the bm.isAlive returns true and I think that is because it is a websockets implementation that never has a known end. This is causing issues with getting info on my second call.

Comment: The client lib is there too. Here is the parent directory so you can access both libs 
  https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/tree/master/binance